# How to customize Google Sheets embed

Tags: google-sheets

Back in the day, I know it was possible to really customize your Google Docs/Forms. Is that still the case? There were all these tricks about how to make it look the way you want when you embed them onto a page (and remove Google's branding). [The closest post](https://wp-glogin.com/2014/08/embedding-google-spreadsheets-with-more-control-over-appearance/) I'm finding is from 2014 and it doesn't appear to work anymore.

What I'm trying to do is embed a small table into a webpage -- and only that table. I don't want anything else from Google. This table will be updated by me on the backend, so it can't be just an image.

Comment: You have to [publish to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965) and then get the iframe code to embed. At the top of your Spreadsheet , click File and then Publish to the web. Click on the Embed tab and then on the "Publish" button, this will generate the iframe element you can use in your web. Is that what you needed?

Comment: Thanks for your help! What I'm looking for is the ability to really customize the appearance of the Google Sheet within its iframe. The example I linked to allowed you to pull out just specific cells from Google Sheets and embed them onto your page. That'd be an awesome application instead of trying to embed the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [publish to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965) and then get the iframe code to embed. At the top of your Spreadsheet, click `File` and then Publish to the web. Click on the Embed tab and then on the "Publish" button, this will generate the iframe element you can use in your web.

Within the iframe, there's the `src` attribute with a URL you can edit with some query parameters to customize Sheet's [behaviors](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965), for example, to specify the range to be displayed in the iframe, you can add the `range` query parameter:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/[SPREADSHEET-ID]/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;range=[RANGE]&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

In your case it would appear your Spreadsheet ID and you need to replace the [RANGE] with the A1 notation of the range you want to display.